# How to automatically pass multiple inputs to prompts in circleci?

Tags: python-3.x, shell, circleci, cookiecutter

I am trying to apply a cookiecutter template. When I run the command "cookiecutter private_git_repo", it asks if I want to use overlays or not? So, I need to pass "yes" to that. Later, it gives multiple options to ask which overlay I want to use. Since, I want to achieve this in circleci config, I want an automatic way to pass "yes" and "overlay_name" to the command.

I am not able to use | to pass multiple inputs to the prompt questions. How can one achieve this in linux terminal?

Answer (score 0):

From the docs here: https://cookiecutter.readthedocs.io/en/latest/readme.html

```
Unless you suppress it with --no-input, you are prompted for input.
```

**Short Answer**: you need to run **cookiecutter private_git_repo --no-input** in order to bypass the command prompt asking you to type **yes**.

However, can you please clarify what you mean when you say that you get prompted for "overlays"?  I'm not familiar with the term "overlays" in cookiecutter. Do you mean templates?

Comment: Yes, I mean templates.

Comment: cool. Can you please edit your question say templates instead of overlays?

Also - Did you try the --no-input flag as I suggested in my answer?